# Use the fact that |a' x b'| = |a'||b'|sin($\theta$), where $\theta$ is the angle between a' and b', to show that T(S) has area |det(A)|

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the linear transformation $T$: ℝ$^2$ $\rightarrow$ ℝ$^2$, (x,y) $\mapsto$ A (x,y)

for some 2x2 matrix A and let S be the unit square with corners {(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)}.

Suppose that A =

\begin{matrix}
        \ a_1 & b_1 \\
        a_2 & b_2 \\
        \end{matrix}

Use the fact that $|$$a'$ x $b'$$|$ = $|a'||b'|sin$($\theta$), where $\theta$ is the angle between $a'$ and $b'$, to show that $T(S)$ has area $|det(A)|$.

I honestly don't know where to start. I've watched the following video https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/determinant-depth/v/linear-algebra-determinant-and-area-of-a-parallelogram but I do not understand how to specifically prove it, as this question is asking. If someone could please help, I would greatly appreciate it. Please explain each step and why you are doing it. This way I can learn.

Answer (score 1):

Unit square $S$ is defined by a point $O = (0,0)$ and two vectors starting in this point $O$: $\vec{v_1} = (0,1)^T,\; \vec{v_2} = (1, 0)^T$.

$T(\vec{v_1}) =  A\vec{v_1} = (b_1, b_2)^T,\; T(\vec{v_2}) =  A\vec{v_2} = (a_1, a_2)^T.$ Area of $T(S)$ equals $|A\vec{v_1} \times A\vec{v_2}| = \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} \cdot \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2} \cdot \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta},$ but $\cos \theta$ can be computed from the scalar product: $\cos \theta = \dfrac{a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} \cdot \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2}}$

Substitute this into the previous formula and obtain
$|A\vec{v_1} \times A\vec{v_2}| = \sqrt{(a_1^2 + a_2^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2) - (a_1 b_1  + a_2 b_2)^2} = \sqrt{a_1^2 b_2^2 + a_2^2 b_1^2 - 2 a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2} = |a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1| = |\det A|$

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'but cos $\theta$ can be computed from the scalar product'.

Comment: @ThePointer scalar product $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ (or it's denoted by $(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$) equals $|\vec{a}| \cdot |\vec{b}| \cdot \cos \theta$ and at the same time it's equal to $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2$ in Cartesian coordinate system.